# How do I enable UI calls from a c# console application? Using PowerShell Get-Credential

Tags: c#, powershell, user-interface, console-application

I have a Windows console application calling powershell cmdlets. I would like to have the `Get-Credential` UI popup at the front of the program, but I get an exception stating that the calling application does not support this.

I've read a bit and it seems like I may need to inherit from `PSHostUserInterface`. Can anyone confirm this and possibly point me towards a sample app?

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.Runspace = runspace;
    ps.AddCommand("Get-Credential")
        .AddParameter("Credential", "UserName")
        .AddParameter("Message", "Prompt Message Here")
        .Invoke();
```

This generates the following exception:

> *"Cannot process argument transformation on parameter* `'Credential'`*. A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message:* `Enter your credentials.`*"*

Comment: Can you show the code that's now working?

Comment: Ok, posted the code and the exception it generates.

Comment: Have you considered using the C# application to capture credential details and then passing them to PowerShell? I use this line to do something similar: `New-Object PSCredential($Username, $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force))`.

Comment: Yes, in fact that part appears to be working. So, I really don't need an answer to this question any longer. I guess I should answer it and mark it closed. Even though I would really like to know if it's possible to have the popup, that removes the burden of keeping the password in a secure file.